# Objective-C: Modulo bias

Tags: objective-c, random

Using:

```
value = arc4random() % x
```

How can I avoid or eliminate modulo bias?

At least according to Wikipedia, modulo bias is an issue when programming games of chance.

Comment: Consider re-marking Zoidberg's answer as the correct one, as it's the canonical correct answer according to the authors of arc4random().

Comment: [What is modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

arc4random returns a 32-bit unsigned integer (0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1).

There will probably be no noticable modulo bias for small enough x. However, if you want to be really sure, do this:

y = 2<sup>p</sup> where 2<sup>p-1</sup> < x ≤ 2<sup>p</sup>

```
val = arc4random() % y;
while(val >= x)
    val = arc4random() % y;
```

Comment: If I recall, there's something like this in Python's random number generator.

Comment: I happen to trip over same task, C implementation can be found in OpenBSD `arc4random_uniform()` at [src/sys/dev/rnd.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/dev/rnd.c?rev=1.140;content-type=text%2Fplain)

Answer (score 49):

Use `arc4random_uniform(x)`. This does it for you.

According to the man page:

> `arc4random_uniform()` will return a uniformly distributed random number less than `upper_bound`. `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended over constructions like `arc4random() % upper_bound` as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Answer (score 4):

```
u_int32_t maxValue = ~((u_int32_t) 0);      // equal to 0xffff...
maxValue -= maxValue % x;                   // make maxValue a multiple of x
while((value = arc4random()) >= maxValue) { // loop until we get 0 ≤ value < maxValue
}
value %= x;
```

although unless you are using any x under a million (or more) I wouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 2):

If the maximum value of `arc4random` mod `x` is greater than `x`, ignore any values larger than the largest `arc4random-max mod x`, calling `arc4random` again instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
u_int32_t maxValue = ~((u_int32_t) 0);      // equal to 0xffff...
maxValue -= maxValue % x;                   // make maxValue a multiple of x
while((value = arc4random()) >= maxValue) { // loop until we get 0 ≤ value < maxValue
}
value %= x;
```

Somewhat pedantic objection to cobbal's answer. It "works", that is it removes the modulo bias, but it rejects more values than are necessary. The most extreme case is x = 2^31. All values of arc4random() should be accepted here but the code as written will reject half of them.

Instead, add 1 to the initialization of maxValue (that puts it at 2^32 so you'll have to use a 64 bit int), and then it's right. You can also avoid using a 64 bit int. Test beforehand if 2^32 % x == 0, if so all arc4random() values are acceptable and you can skip the loop, otherwise you can keep maxValue at 32 bits by subtracting 2^32 % x on initialization.