# How to select range of values when using arc4random()

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

Can I set a range of numbers when using arc4random()? For example 50-100 only.

Comment: use the modulo for the range and add the offset to it, like arc4random() % 50 + 50; it will provide you a random number in range of 50 and 99.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As pointed out in other posts below, it is better to use `arc4random_uniform`. (When this answer was originally written, `arc4random_uniform` was not available). Besides avoiding the modulo bias of `arc4random() % x`, it also avoids a seeding problem with `arc4random` when used recursively in short timeframes.

```
arc4random_uniform(4)
```

will generate 0, 1, 2 or 3. Thus you could use:

```
arc4random_uniform(51)
```

and merely add 50 to the result to get a range between 50 & 100 (inclusive).

Comment: This only gives you 0 to 50, doesn't give you a range of 50 to 100.

Comment: Like Run Loop said add 50. int num = (arc4random() % (51)) +50;

Comment: Beware of this method's [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias). Safer to use [`arc4random_uniform()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648739/objective-c-modulo-bias).

Comment: I've expanded @JohnK thoughts in an answer below. If you want a more accurate random number distribution then it's definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 29):

To expand upon JohnK comment.

It is suggested that you use the following function to return a ranged random number:

```
arc4random_uniform(51)
```

which will return a random number in the range `0` to `50`.

Then you can add your lower bounds to this like:

```
arc4random_uniform(51) + 50
```

which will return a random number in the range `50` to `100`.

The reason we use `arc4random_uniform(51)` over `arc4random() % 51` is to avoid the [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias). This is highlighted in the man page as follows:

> arc4random_uniform(upper_bound) will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound. arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

In short you get a more evenly distributed random number generated.

Answer (score 19):

```
int fromNumber = 10;
int toNumber = 30;
int randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
```

Will generate `randon number` between `10` and `30`, i.e. `11,12,13,14......29`

Comment: It's (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber+1))+fromNumber

Comment: Beware of this method's [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias). Safer to use [`arc4random_uniform()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648739/objective-c-modulo-bias).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for generating random values with range:

```
//range from 50 to 100
int num1 = (arc4random() % 50) + 50; or
int num1 = arc4random_uniform(50) + 50;

//range from 0-100
int num1 = arc4random() % 100; or
int num1 = arc4random_uniform(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can use this (inspired by answer of [@Justyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670540/1415713))

```
func generateRandomKey(fromRange rangeFrom:Int, toRange rangeTo:Int) -> Int{

    let theKey = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rangeTo - rangeFrom)) +  UInt32(rangeFrom)
    return Int(theKey)
}
```

Will always give you a random range Integer.

Comment: I think this needs adjusting as your range will always be 1 less that you want. You should increment your rangeTo by 1.

'let theKey = arc4random_uniform(UInt32((rangeTo + 1) - rangeFrom)) +  UInt32(rangeFrom)'

Comment: Also, if you're wanting to generate a random key, you should probably be looking at this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428458/1130260

Answer (score 0):

In many situations 10 thru 30 would mean inclusive, (includes 10 and 30) ...

```
int fromNumber = 10;
int toNumber = 30;
toNumber ++;
int randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
```

Notice the difference toNumber - fromNumber is now 21 ... (20+1) which yields the possible results of 0 thru 20 (inclusive) which when added to fromNumber (10) results in 10 thru 30 (inclusive).

Comment: Beware of this method's [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modulo_bias). Safer to use [`arc4random_uniform()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648739/objective-c-modulo-bias).