# How to generate a random number in a range (10...20) using Swift

Tags: swift, random, range

I'm able to pick a random number for my items in my game but
is it possible to pick a random number between 2 numbers?

so instead of

```
let number = (arc4random_uniform(100))
```

I would like something like this:

```
let number = (arc4random_uniform(10...20))
```

or something like that?
Now if I get a weapon drop it can be everything in my list.
This way I could make it so that only the first few would have a drop for a specific monster or at higher level they would drop better weapons and not the low levels anymore.

Comment: Another potential dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3420581/2415822

Comment: Not a dupe, please read before duping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

```
extension Range where Bound: FixedWidthInteger {
    var random: Bound { .random(in: self) }
    func random(_ n: Int) -> [Bound] { (0..<n).map { _ in random } }
}
```

---

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound: FixedWidthInteger  {
    var random: Bound { .random(in: self) }
    func random(_ n: Int) -> [Bound] { (0..<n).map { _ in random } }
}
```

**Note:** For older Swift versions check the edit history

**Usage:**

```
(10...20).random    // 16
(0...1).random(10)  // [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Do not use `hashValue` here – the value that it returns is an implementation detail and therefore subject to change (it just *happens* to return an `Int` of the same value in this case). Always returning 0 would be a valid (albeit ineffective) `hashValue` implementation, but would completely break your random logic. A more reliable way would be to go via `IntMax` instead – for example `Int(lowerBound.toIntMax()) + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((upperBound - lowerBound + 1).toIntMax())))`.

Comment: Also IMO, a method would be more appropriate than a computed property here, as invoking it repeatedly can yield different results (not something I would expect a computed property to do).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the input. I agree that toIntMax() is the appropriate approach but I prefer it as a computed property. I use computed properties for everything and I never expect it to be static.

Comment: This code gives the illusion that it works with arbitrary integers. But it crashes if `upperBound - lowerBound + 1` exceeds the UInt32 range. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391577/how-can-i-generate-large-ranged-random-numbers-in-swift for some code which works with "large" integers.

Comment: Btw, using `reduce` as a `map` replacement is highly ineffective.