# How do I put a limit for the computer to pick a number randomly. This limit is already picked by the user

Tags: swift, arc4random

This line of code is not working.

```
    randnum = Double(arc4random() % Double(limit))
```

The error gives Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'Double'

How do I get the computer to select a random number between 0 and the limit picked by the user.

Comment: Is `limit` small enough to fit on `int`?

Comment: nevermind i have fixed my problem, thank you for the other links.

Comment: According to Apple, use `arc4random_uniform(limit)` instead of `arc4random() % limit` to avoid modulo bias. Here's the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712601/2303865