# How do I randomize a position negatively?

Tags: swift

So I have to randomize an x position. But for some reason the middle is 0 and therefore I need to do negative max x and positive max x. It's a little hard to explain so here is the code:

```
let height = UInt32(self.view!.frame.height)
    let nHeight = ((height - height) - height)

    let randomXPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(nHeight)) + height)
```

This doesn't give me any errors but when I run it crashes. I need a way to randomize the value for negative max X and positive max X so that the object is randomized in the screen.

Comment: Perhaps u can use an offsetter ?  if the resolution u are dealing with is -400 to 400, perhaps you can work with number from 0 to 800, then adjust your final positions accordingly?  Also, not sure it's a good idea to mix INT with an UNSIGNED INT since you can run into overflow issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34712601/2303865 you can use negative values with this extension

Answer (score 3):

If you need to generate a random number between -x and x then just create a random number between 0 and 2x and subtract x.  `arc4random_uniform(x * 2) - x`.