# SpriteKit Swift 4 Error: Type 'Int' has no member 'random'

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, swift4

I am making a jumping game using Swift 4 and I am running into an error with the following code:

```
func addRandomForegroundOverlay() {
    let overlaySprite: SKSpriteNode!
    let platformPercentage = 60
    if Int.random(min: 1, max: 100) <= platformPercentage {
        overlaySprite = platform5Across
    } else {
        overlaySprite = coinArrow
    }
    createForegroundOverlay(overlaySprite, flipX: false)
}
```

The error comes on line 4 and says: Type `Int` has no member `random`.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712453/random-number-x-amount-till-x-amount-swift/34712601#34712601

Comment: based on that link, it seems as though I need to use extensions?

Comment: you just need to add a new Swift file into your project and add those extensions there

Comment: Thanks, Leo Dabus. It actually worked without needing the extensions.

Comment: I know that. It was just an alternative syntax. `Int(arc4random_uniform(100))+1` is enough for what you need

Answer (score 1):

The `Int` type doesn't provide a `random()` method.

Since you are making a game, using `GameplayKit.GKRandom` might be a good fit. Try this instead:

```
import GameplayKit
...
let randomizer = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom()
let randomInt = 1 + randomizer.nextInt(upperBound: 100) // 1...100
```

Or, better yet, implement the missing method yourself ;)

```
extension Int {
    static func random(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
        precondition(min <= max)
        let randomizer = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom()
        return min + randomizer.nextInt(upperBound: max - min + 1)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let randomInt = Int.random(min: 1, max: 100)
```

Comment: How do I do this using SpriteKit?

Comment: Pretty easy: add `import GameplayKit` at the top of your file; and then add my  `extension Int { ...` outside any classes in this same file.

Comment: ...and you may also need to include the `GameplayKit` framework in your Xcode project, if you haven't done it already.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use `Int(arc4random_uniform(100))`

Comment: this would return a number from 0 to 99. not from 1...100. `Int(arc4random_uniform(100))+1`

Comment: Leo Dabus ... Does your answer include only numbers 1 through 100?