# arc4random Swift 3 syntax

Tags: swift, xcode, random, swift3

I made a quiz app in Swift 2 I'm trying to update the syntax from random to arc4random...

```
if Questions.count > 0 && counter <= 15 {
            QNumber = arc4random()% Questions.count
            QLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

        AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<Buttons.count{
            Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState())
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. (Also, there's no need for the modulo; you should use `arc4random_uniform` instead, with a parameter, as that will [avoid modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420581/how-to-select-range-of-values-when-using-arc4random))

Comment: Please consider to conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter. Your code is very hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to use `arc4random_uniform` instead of simple `arc4random`.

`arc4random_uniform` expects an `UInt32` parameter so you have to convert the values back and forth

```
qNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
```

Comment: Does the upper bound get included in the possible results?  For example, if questions.count were 100, would arc4random_uniform generate a random number between 0-99 inclusive, or 1-100 inclusive?

Comment: From the documentation: *The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1* so if you need 1-100 pass 99 and add 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `arc4random_uniform()`. That function wants to communicate with `UInt32`s, which requires some casting between types.

```
let questions = ["What is love?", "What's the capital of Mongolia?"]
let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
print(questions[index])
```