# memory game in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a memory game in obj-c. I have 6 UIButtons as cards and 3 pairs of pictures. I just `arc4Random() % 3` for each button to get a new image every time view loads. My problem is that, obviously, for example all buttons could have the same image since it just takes a random number. How can I make sure only 2 images of each pair is generated?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if I was you I would look at the Stanford iTunesU course. They actually implement this exact game. It is also extremely informational beyond just the game implementation.

Comment: To avoid modulo bias `arc4random_uniform(3)` should be used instead of `arc4Random() % 3`, see man page.

Comment: @Firo Thanks I'm going to take a look at it!

Comment: @GerdK what is the difference?

Comment: @Wilhelm Michaelsen  See [this discussion about modulo bias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648739/objective-c-modulo-bias).

Comment: @Firo where can I find that tutorial?

Comment: Here's a link to the courses, you can also find then in iTunes (in iTunes U section, I download them so I can watch them offline): https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

---

Here is a link to the course material: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the images in an array, shuffle it, and then iterate on it, setting the buttons' images.

Comment: could you please explain briefly how that is done?